# How can I reduce the 70 GB of storage that is classified as system space on my MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, storage

Am using Mac Book Pro 2017 model 128 GB.Am using ios development purpose. but some time memory management alert. Here my mac using system space above 70 GB. How can i reduce my system space.

[image]

Comment: If you open About this Mac in system preferences, what is the colorful graph showing for purgeabke space and system space? An edit to show that might yield some clues

Comment: Check with Disk Inventory X. Don’t go randomly deleting files, but do post an update on the actual space distribution.

Comment: System is how much space macOS is taking up on your Mac, generally you can't reduce that unless you have a large number of cache/temp/log files. Try a disk cleanup utility like Onyx.

Comment: DaisyDisk and Onyx, plus active RAM management via Memory Cleaner keep my MBP 2011 (only 16 Gb RAM) humming a long even doing huge 3D modeling and rendering tasks.

Comment: iOS device simulator would also take about 3 GB by each version, in case you have both iOS 9.3, 10.1 and 11.3 installed, if any of the versions you don't need any more, you should remove it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the build-in `Storage Management.app` for inspecting what file is consuming large amount of disk space

Another software [Daisy Disk](https://daisydiskapp.com/) is very useful for disk space visualising, so you can easily find out the large directories or files by checking the sector area (for directories that contains its files and sub directories)

Comment: am already tried the Storage Management.app but i can't reduce the system space

Comment: @Karthickkck it is only used for checking out which file or app is too large, so you can manually delete it, it can not reduce space usage by deleting automatically. For the judgement of which file is important or not, it depends on yourself. If some of the Apple app is not used by you, like GarageBand, iMovie, Pages, Numbers, Keynotes, would take quite amount of space, when I delete GarageBand and its sound library, I save up about 8 GB of space

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue but just solved it. You can use from here [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/). It will shows you the detail information about your storage. From there you can delete unuseful files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OmniDiskSweeper to analyse the files that occupies most of your space and at the same time can delete files too
.I hav solved my mac storage issue using this software.